# Infinite sequence of 2-dimensional subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

> I want to show that in $\mathbb{R^4}$ there is an infinite sequence of $2-$dimensional subspaces $W_1, W_2, \dots$ such that for each $i \neq j$ we have $W_i \cap W_j = \{0\}$. How do I go about this?

**Edit:**

After some thought I have come up with this. If we write down a 4 by 4 matrix $A = [\alpha_1 \alpha_2 \alpha_3 \alpha_4]$ where $\alpha_i$ are independent column vectors, than the column vectors span $\mathbb{R^4}$. Now, let's choose two of the vectors, say, $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$. They span a 2-dimensional vector space, which we will denote as $W_1$. $\alpha_3$ and $\alpha_4$ span $W_2$ and $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{0\}$. We repeat this process ad infinitum, getting $W_1, W_2, W_3, W_4, \dots$ which is the desired infinite sequence. Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1):

Think of it geometrically ,

First consider in $\Bbb R^2$:

In order to get a one-dimensional subspace in $\Bbb R^2$ we take a non-zero vector $v_0$ in $\Bbb R^2$ and consider the $\text{span} \{v_0\}=\{\alpha v_0:\alpha\in \Bbb R\}$ which gives a straight line say $L$ in  $\Bbb R^2$.

Now choose a point $v$ outside $L$ which is available since $\Bbb R^2$ has dimension $2$ over $\Bbb R$. Again consider the $\text{span} \{v\}=\{\alpha v:\alpha\in \Bbb R\}$ which is $L^{'}$ say. Definitely $L\cap L^{'}=\{0\}$

How many such sub-spaces can be constructed?

Infinitely many since there are uncountably many straight lines passing through the point $\{(0,0)\}$ and each straight line gives a one-dimensional subspace.

With the same logic as above, repeat the process in $\Bbb R^4$ with **lines** replaced with **two-dimensionalplanes**